# Data Storage Issue in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I m facing a problem, Cassandra is not storing the data but other commit-log is working. I saw as per seeing the configuration `.yaml` file. I have checked the folder and Cassandra has created a folder in `MYKEYSPACENAME`, but the data is not been stored there.

Is there something that I need to store the data? I m using the Cassandra 1.0.7 version.

Comment: why do you think the data is not stored there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like everything is working normally. When Cassandra receives data to write, it first writes to a commit log and to an in memory data structure (called a Memtable). Once the Memtable is full Cassandra will flush it to an SSTable on disk. You can force Cassandra to flush its Memtables using `nodetool`:

```
nodetool flush [keyspace] [cfnames]
```

This is not something that you need to do for normal operation of a Cassandra ring. Cassandra will eventually flush the Memtables to disk. If for some reason one of your Cassandra machines goes down, when it restarts it will replay the commit log so you will not lose any previously received writes.

The [Cassandra wiki has more information on Memtables and SSTables](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/MemtableSSTable).